# Added the focus when the property being empty field

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I want when I click on the button
If a field name is empty the prbodensh having the mouse pointer to the point that it
I wrote a code that do it myself, but just a moment as it pertains
Then it can be expanded now what should I do?
This is the code that I wrote:

```
if($('#name').val=='')
{
$('#name').focus();
```

Comment: Please try to use some interpunction in your question. Also don't make your sentences soooo long. That way we could probably have an easier understanding of what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop the execution from further continuing,

```
if($('#name').val() =='')
{
$('#name').focus();
return false;
}
```